# tkinter: using message box icons in my own child window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

is it possible to use one of those standard messagebox icons in a custom child window? I need it to build a more complex messagebox containing some text, three buttons and a checkbox.

Thanks.

Comment: Use TkMessageBox. http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-standard-dialogs.htm

Comment: Not possible because I need custom button labels. By the way, this problem still exists, so if anybody knows a solution - please help.